# What's the difference between these two functions in Tkinter?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Why are these two functions different?

```
    def other_entry1(self, selection, row, el, var):
        if selection == "Other":
            var = StringVar()
            el = Entry(self.frame1, textvariable=var)
            el.grid(row=row, column=6)
    #Calling it as part of an optionMenu
    self.e33 = OptionMenu(self.frame1, self.ea_tf, *fixtures, command= lambda selection:self.other_entry1(selection,15, self.e33, self.ea_tf))
```

The other one:

```
    def other_entry2(self, selection):
        if selection == "Other":
            self.ea_tf = StringVar()
            self.e33 = Entry(self.frame1, textvariable=self.ea_tf)
            self.e33.grid(row=15, column=6)

    #Calling it in an optionMenu
    self.e33 = OptionMenu(self.frame1, self.ea_tf, *fixtures, command=self.other_entry2)
```

I would like to be able to call the first function several times and just tell it what entry box to create instead of making several separate functions.

Edit: Isn't the second function just skipping the step of substituting in the arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.s33` is **reference to** `OptionMenu`

Second function overwrite `self.e33` by reference to `Entry` and you can't use `self.e33` to get access to `OptionMenu`.

First function copy reference from `self.s33` to `el` then overwrites `el` by reference to `Entry` but you can still use `self.s33` to get access to `OptionMenu`

See simple example using "Visual Execution" on PythonTutor.com:

Use link to open page with example, click "Visual Execution" and then you can use "Forward" button to see step by step how example works

- [function 1](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+other_entry1(el,+val)%3A%0A++++el+%3D+%5B%22x%22,+%22y%22,+%22z%22%5D%0A++++val+%3D+%5B9,8,7%5D%0A++++%0A%0Aea_tf+%3D+%5B%22a%22,+%22b%22,+%22c%22%5D%0As33+%3D+%5B1,2,3%5D%0A%0A%0Aother_entry1(ea_tf,+s33)&mode=edit&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2)
- [function 2](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+other_entry1()%3A%0A++++global+ea_tf,+s33%0A++++ea_tf+%3D+%5B%22x%22,+%22y%22,+%22z%22%5D%0A++++s33+%3D+%5B9,8,7%5D%0A++++%0A%0Aea_tf+%3D+%5B%22a%22,+%22b%22,+%22c%22%5D%0As33+%3D+%5B1,2,3%5D%0A%0A%0Aother_entry1()&mode=edit&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2)

---

You can use first function to create several `Entry` but you don't need to send `self.e33` and `self.ea_tf` because function will not use it.

You get the same result as

```
def other_entry1(self, selection, row):
    if selection == "Other":
        var = StringVar()
        Entry(self.frame1, textvariable=var).grid(row=row, column=6)

#Calling it as part of an optionMenu
self.e33 = OptionMenu(self.frame1, self.ea_tf, *fixtures, command=lambda selection:self.other_entry1(selection,15))
```

problem is with access to `Entry` or `StringVar()` to get value from `Entry`

```
self.all_vars = {} # dictionary

def other_entry1(self, selection, row):
    if selection == "Other":
        self.all_vars[row] = StringVar()
        Entry(self.frame1, textvariable=self.all_vars[row]).grid(row=row, column=6)

#Calling it as part of an optionMenu
self.e33 = OptionMenu(self.frame1, self.ea_tf, *fixtures, command=lambda selection:self.other_entry1(selection,15))

# another place

row = 15
print "row:", row
print "value in Entry:", self.all_vars[row].get()
```

---

**EDIT:** working example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *

class App():

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.all_entries = {} # empty dictionary
        self.all_entries_vars = {} # empty dictionary

        self.all_optionmenus = {} # empty dictionary
        self.all_optionmenus_vars = {} # empty dictionary

        fixtures = ["One", "Two", "Tree", "Other"]

        # create 5 options menu
        for i in range(5):
            self.all_optionmenus_vars[i] = StringVar()
            self.all_optionmenus_vars[i].set("One")

            self.all_optionmenus[i] = OptionMenu(self.master, self.all_optionmenus_vars[i], *fixtures, command=lambda selection, col=i:self.addEntry(selection, col))
            self.all_optionmenus[i].grid(row=1, column=i)

        Button(master, text="Print OptionMenus Vars", command=self.printOptionMenus).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5)
        Button(master, text="Print Entries Vars", command=self.printEntries).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=5)

    def run(self):
        self.master.mainloop()

    def addEntry(self, selection, col):

        if selection == "Other":

            # if Entry was created before
            if col in self.all_entries:
                # show existing Entry
                self.all_entries[col].grid(row=0, column=col)
            else:
                # create new Entry
                self.all_entries_vars[col] = StringVar()
                self.all_entries[col] = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.all_entries_vars[col])
                self.all_entries[col].grid(row=0, column=col)

        # if Entry was created before
        elif col in self.all_entries:
            # hide Entry
            self.all_entries[col].grid_forget()

    def printEntries(self):
        print "-"*30
        for key in self.all_entries_vars:
            print "Entry #%d: %s" % ( key, self.all_entries_vars[key].get() )

    def printOptionMenus(self):
        print "-"*30
        for key in self.all_optionmenus_vars:
            print "OptionMenu #%d: %s" % ( key, self.all_optionmenus_vars[key].get() )


#----------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App(Tk()).run()
```

[image]

Comment: What should the dictionary look like `self.all_vars = {15:self.ea_tf, 16:self.var2}`? If i use this on more than one option menu, it only retrieves the entry box's value of the last one created. How can i make this work for several different variables?

Comment: You create only empty directory `self.all_vars = {}`, `other_entry1` will add new elements to directory. I try to do working example.

Comment: It isn't adding values to the dictionary. When i try to call self.all_vars[15].get(), it returns 'KeyError: 15'.

Comment: Add more `print` to see what's going on in code. It wasn't full program so I can't test it. I add full working example.

Comment: I have been trying that, but i can't figure it out. I am just going to make the function more specific/longer. No need for an example, thank you for your help!